# Javascript array datatable conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I have a json string which is feeding a javascript page, I am trying to render on the screen, by using the following code, but my conditional logic is not working, what I want to accomplish is if there is not data returned print a blank space, otherwise show and icon. Thanks.

JSON

"SCHEDULES":{
 "RCOUNT":186,
 "SCHEDULE":[
 {
  "CASEID":18397020.000000,
  "SCHEDAREA":"SURG",
  "LASTDIETORDERNAME":"",
  "LASTDIETORDERSTARTDT":"",
}

Javascript

```
var dietTable = [];

dietTable.push(
    "<table id='dataTable' class='dataTable' cellpadding=0 cellspacing =0>"
        ,"<tr id='dataTableTH'>"
            ,"<th class='headers' style='text-align:left;white-space: nowrap;'>Diet</th>"
            ,"<th class='headers' style='text-align:left;white-space: nowrap;'>Date Time</th>"
        ,"</tr>"
);
dietTable.push(
    "<tr>"
        ,"<td style='vertical-align:top;text-align:left'>",ptDiet,"</td>"
        ,"<td style='vertical-align:top;text-align:left'>",ptDietDT,"</td>"
    ,"</tr>"
);
dietTable.push("</table>");

if(SCHEDULES.LASTDIETORDERSTARTDT !== null) {
    dietVal = ['<img border =0 src="..//..//images//dietIcon2.png " width="20px" height="20px" title="'+dietTable.join("")+'">'];
} else {
    dietVal = ["&nbsp;"];
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working". Have you checked the value of `SCHEDULES.LASTDIETORDERSTARTDT` before condition? What is it?

Comment: how are we supposed to help troubleshoot a conditional if you don't provide data sample? I doubt you want to use an expicit `!== null`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say is still showing the icon wether there is a value in SCHEDULES.LASTDIETORDERSTARTDT or no.

Comment: so my guess, is that is comparing only to the first element of the array, how can I loop through it?

Comment: Maybe not an exact dup, but [useful reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1169519) about equals operators.

Answer (score 0):

This Did it, thanks

if(SCHEDULES.LASTDIETORDERSTARTDT !== "")